# Completion of a normed space using an isometry

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm practicing some old exams for my functional analysis exam tomorrow, and i'm having trouble with the following:

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space and let $Y$ be a normed space. Assume there exists a linear map $T: Y\to X$ which is an isometry.

A completion $(Z, i)$ of a normed space $Y$ consists of a Banach space $Z$ and an isometry $i : Y \to Z$ such that $\overline{i(Y)} = Z$.

a) Construct a completion $Z$ of $Y$ using $T$.

b) Prove that the completion $Z$ in a) is a reflexive space.

Comment: Are you sure about the formulation? $X=\lbrace 0\rbrace$ is a reflexive Banach space and the zero map $T:X\to Y$ is an isometry which certainly does not help to construct a completion of $Y$.

Comment: I checked again, i literally copied the question... But $T$ is not going from a reflexive space to a normed space with an isometry, but the other direction.

Comment: What is $J_X$??? It looks to me like there is something wrong. You are probably supposed to find a completion of $X$, and it is $Y$ which is a reflexive Banach space, not $X$.

Comment: Sorry, i should have specified $J_X : X \to X'' : x \mapsto (f \mapsto f(x))$

Comment: But you wrote $T:X\to Y$. For an isometry $T:Y\to X$ you can just take $Z=\overline{T(Y)}$ and $i=T$ (if you are very scrupulous, define $i:Y\to Z$ by $i(y)=T(y)$ -- it is a different map because of the codomain). $Z$ is reflexive because closed subspaces of reflexive Banach spaces are reflexive. This can be proved, e.g., using the characterization of  reflexivity by weak compactness of the closed unit ball.

Comment: Thanks @Jochen. Since $X$ is Banach and $\overline{T(Y)}$ is closed, it is also Banach. Way easier than my solution! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Let $Z = \overline{T(Y)}$. Then $Z$ is a closed subspace of a Banach space and hence a Banach space. Define $i = T$. Then $i$ is an isometry and $\overline{i(Y)} = \overline{T(Y)} = Z$. So $(Z,i)$ is a completion of $Y$.

b) Z is a closed subspace of a reflexive space, so it is reflexive.